# Appending to/changing far right column of a existing .csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a hard time trying to modify name of the column in my .csv file. I'm uploading my .csv report to a platform that requires it to end with `";"` sign. I'm using csv.writer, and was trying to just append the symbol at the end of the header list in the first row, but without success.

```
HEADER_LIST: list = ["NAME_1", "NAME_2", "NAME_3", "NAME_4", "NAME_5", "NAME_6"]

def writing_to_csv(CSV_PATH, FILE_TO_WRITE) -> Path:
   pathFile: Path = Path(CSV_PATH).joinpath(FILE_TO_WRITE)
   rows = zip(LIST_1, LIST_2, LIST_3, LIST_4, LIST_5, LIST_6)
   with open(pathFile.as_posix(), "w+", newline='') as csv_file:
       to_write = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
       to_write.writerow(HEADER_LIST)
       for row in rows:
          to_write.writerow(row)

   return pathFile
```

This code returns me with a .csv file that looks like:

```
NAME_1;NAME_2;NAME_3;NAME_4:NAME_5;NAME_6
EL_1_LIST_1;EL_1_LIST_2;EL_1_LIST_3;EL_1_LIST_4;EL_1_LIST_5;EL_1_LIST_6
EL_2_LIST_1, ...
```

Tried to open my .csv file again and append to first row with header using another function:

```
def add_semicolon_to_csv(CSV_PATH, FILE_TO_WRITE):
   pathFile: Path = Path(CSV_PATH).joinpath(FILE_TO_WRITE)
   with open(pathFile.as_posix(), "a+", newline='') as csv_file:
       to_append = csv.writer(csv_file)
       to_append.writerow(";")
```

But instead of my desired output that would look like this:

```
NAME_1;NAME_2;NAME_3;NAME_4:NAME_5;NAME_6;
EL_1_LIST_1;EL_1_LIST_2;EL_1_LIST_3;EL_1_LIST_4;EL_1_LIST_5;EL_1_LIST_6
EL_2_LIST_1, ...
```

It changes my file like this:

```
NAME_1;NAME_2;NAME_3;NAME_4:NAME_5;NAME_6
EL_1_LIST_1;EL_1_LIST_2;EL_1_LIST_3;EL_1_LIST_4;EL_1_LIST_5;EL_1_LIST_6
EL_2_LIST_1, ...
;
```

Could someone point where is the problem within my code? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And why do you have colons in some cases?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code and make sure your code is free of syntax errors so others can help you.

Comment: Well, this is needed by a report collecting engine. It's not my desire to do so, for the sake of doing it. And it gave me a headache, cause I spent almost two days now trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Like you and a commenter noted, the report platform has non-CSV standard requirement that the header (only?) have a trailing semicolon.

You can force this with the csv module by simply writing an *empty field* for your header row (or any other rows that need it):

```py
import csv

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    w.writerow(["a", "b", "c", ""])  # empty trailing field forces trailing delimiter (to appease report platform)
    w.writerow(["1", "2", "3"])
```

That creates an output.csv file that looks like:

```
a;b;c;
1;2;3
```

The writer sees the empty field, "", after "c" and adds the specified delimiter and then writes an empty string (0 characters).  Also, only use "w" for normal write mode, and include newline="" to make sure that the underlying file writing mechanisms don't normalize (change) your line terminators on the fly.

Since this isn't a real CSV problem, you might want to handle it outside of the CSV-crafting code.  This requires a lot more code, and some finesse for dealing with newlines:

```py
# Write "normal" CSV
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    w.writerow(["a", "b", "c"])
    w.writerow(["1", "2", "3"])


# Open CSV and get all lines as text, modifying just the header.
all_lines: list[str] = []

# Use newline="" so open() leaves line terminators as they are.
with open("output.csv", newline="") as f:
    # Get header
    line1 = next(f)

    # Determine where the line terminator starts
    x = -1
    if line1.endswith("\r\n"):
        x = len(line1) - 2
    elif line1.endswith("\n"):
        x = len(line1) - 1
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            f"expected header to end with linefeed (\\n) or CRLF (\\r\\n); last 5 chars of header are {repr(line1[-5:])}"
        )

    # Insert the semicolon just before line terminator
    line1 = line1[:x] + ";" + line1[x:]

    # Append the modified header, then extend the rest of the file as-is
    all_lines.append(line1)
    all_lines.extend(f)


# Create final CSV
with open("output_final.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    f.writelines(all_lines)
```